# Is your activity still running/Accelerometer ?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am using this program code to count no. of situps(crunches) done by user using device accelerometer. It runs fine but some time it crashes with error 'is your activity still running'.

Following is my code :

```
public class SessionActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener,OnClickListener {
    SensorManager sManager;


TextView tvCount;

enum CrunchStatus {
    PEAK_REACHED, PEAK_NOT_REACHED
}

CrunchStatus crStatus;
int counter = 0;
WakeLock wL;
Button btDone,btCancelSess;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.session);

    tvCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCount);        
    crStatus = CrunchStatus.PEAK_NOT_REACHED;

    btDone=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btDone);      
    btDone.setOnClickListener(this);

    btCancelSess=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btQuitSess);        
    btCancelSess.setOnClickListener(this);      

    sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sManager.registerListener(this,sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wL = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    wL.release();
    sManager.unregisterListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    wL.acquire();
    sManager.registerListener(this,sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);             
}


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    double z;
    z=event.values[2];

    if(z<1.5){
        crStatus=CrunchStatus.PEAK_REACHED;
    }
    else if(z>1.5 && crStatus==CrunchStatus.PEAK_REACHED){
        crStatus=CrunchStatus.PEAK_NOT_REACHED;
        counter++;          
        tvCount.setText(""+counter);

    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btDone:
        loadSaveDialog();           
        break;
    case R.id.btQuitSess:
        loadQuitDialog();           
        break;
    }
}



private void loadSaveDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_quit);


    ImageView ivQuitYes=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivQuitYes);
    ivQuitYes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            updateDatabase();
            (SessionActivity.this).finish();
        };
    });

    ImageView ivQuitCancel=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivQuitCancel);
    ivQuitCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        dialog.dismiss();   
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

}


private void loadQuitDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_quit);

    ImageView ivQuitYes=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivQuitYes);
    ivQuitYes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            (SessionActivity.this).finish();
        };
    });

    ImageView ivQuitCancel=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivQuitCancel);
    ivQuitCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        dialog.dismiss();   
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}   
}
```

Following is Error log :

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- 
token android.os.BinderProxy@41ab0c78 
is not valid;is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:513)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
at com.bigdreams.situps.TrainingActivity.loadTimerDialog(TrainingActivity.java:327)
at com.bigdreams.situps.TrainingActivity.onSensorChanged(TrainingActivity.java:223)
at android.hardware.SensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage
(SensorManager.java:580)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you unregistering your listener when the app enters background?

Comment: by background you mean to say when dialog is called ?? No I am not unregistering it. But I tried that too, but it didn't worked. Sometimes it crashes even when dialog is not called.